# SQL Having a single column display value from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need some help. I'm trying to display a field called SubmissionStatus in a query. However I need to select it from multiple tables. For example...

I have:

Table0

Table1.SubmissionStatus
Table2.SubmissionStatus
Table3.SubmissionStatus
(All three of these tables have a foreign key to relate them to Table0)

I can do: 
SELECT Table1.SubmissionStatus, Table2.SubmissionStatus, Table3.SubmissionStatus 
FROM Table0

But that won't give me anything

I need something like: 
SELECT SubmissionStatus FROM Table0  (As one column)

Help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a union, like so:

```
SELECT T1.SubmissionStatus 
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table0 T0 ON T1.primaryKey = T0.foreignKey
UNION
SELECT T2.SubmissionStatus 
FROM Table1 T2
JOIN Table0 T0 ON T2.primaryKey = T0.foreignKey
UNION
SELECT T3.SubmissionStatus 
FROM Table1 T3
JOIN Table0 T0 ON T3.primaryKey = T0.foreignKey
```

That will put everything in one column (think of a union kind of like the JOIN keyword, but for joining rows instead of columns).

Comment: +1, but I would also add a column with the table name so it can be recognized from where that value came from. Just in case

Comment: That's a good idea, Lamak, I like it, though it might not work for Matt, as he mentioned he wants it in one column. But it definitely is worth nothing that the results wouldn't distinguish between tables, so you wouldn't be able to tell where each value came from. Good comment! :)

Comment: Lamak, I actually did need to include the primary key for each table because I had to join it with some things. This was just a subquery in a much larger query. Your input helped.